# Noise spikes with optoisolated circuit driving 12VDC solenoid valve at 6.6 Hz

Tags: mosfet, noise, opto-isolator, solenoid

I have an existing circuit that drives a 12VDC solenoid valve on and off at ~6.7 Hz, 75ms on, 75ms off.   This entire system is DC.
[image]

The Beagle GPIO logic '1' level is 3.3VDC, and the BeagleBone is powered from a separate DC supply. There is no common ground between this circuit's two optically isolated sides.

The circuit controls the valve beautifully.  However, on the BeagleBone side, we get noise spikes in perfect synchronization with the valve going on and off.

The valve has the diode shown in place to address the voltages produced from the collapsing magnetic field when the valve is turned off.

The relatively small spikes (and sometimes have a much larger amplitude) interfere with some important sensor signals in our prototype.

I also get these spikes if I replace the solenoid valve with a 1K ohm, 1/4W wire wound resistor although the magnitude tends to be slightly less, and the occurrence is more sporadic.

Here's a scope capture of the spikes with the solenoid in place.

[image]

FYI: OK1 is a Sharp Microelectronics PC817X1NSZ1B
Q1 is a onsemi TIP122G.

So, two questions.

1. I suspect that either the PC817 optoisolator or the TIP122G produces these spikes and not the solenoid. *If so, what changes will help further reduce or eliminate these spikes?*
2. If it isn't the optoisolator or TIP122, *what can be done further to the solenoid?*  Since it's DC, I don't think a snubber is the answer.

Comment: Worth looking at the loop area of the circuitry on each side. You might well be getting magnetic coupling. Try twisting together the feed and return wires in each circuit to minimize loop area and cancel coupling.

Comment: Where are you measuring these noise spikes?

Comment: Try measuring just on the power supply output.

Comment: I'm measuring with the scope at the board edge connector between the ground terminal and the terminal that the positive lead on the sensor connects.  I'm measuring here because this is where the noise spikes impact our process the most.

Comment: Is there any chance you have the solenoid leads close to the sensor leads, or the BeagleBone controller?  Do you have by-pass filtering on the sensor power leads?  What kind of sensor are you using?  Is it possible that the sensor itself is picking up the noise and then causing the noise on the power leads?

Comment: @nedd the sensor is a custom device that we developed.  It’s primarily a type of light sensor.  We’ve considered what you suggested regarding the sensor.  I’m getting the same noise spikes in the lab without the sensor being connected.  The power to the solenoid is controlled by a TIP122 on the same circuit board as the signal conditioning for the sensor.  However it is optically isolated there.  the circuit that II posted is essentially the same circuit.

Comment: So, after studying this further piece by piece, removing subsystems (BeagleBone, PCB, etc.) one at a time, I have concluded that most of the noise spikes are from the solenoid switching on and off and not from the TIP122 or PC817 optoisolator.   It helps greatly to have the power circuit for the solenoid valve optically isolated from the control circuit.  But there is some radiated noise so distance and properly shielded and grounded cable helps.   There is still some noise which we may be able to handle with software changes now.

Comment: The spikes have a duration of only about 6uS which would translate to around 172kHz.  Could I put a bypass cap across the solenoid's leads to kill this further?